# Fastest way to update all statistics in a database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, parallel.foreach, table-statistics

So I want to run update statistics on all tables in my database. One restriction is   that I cannot run update statistics on more than 20 statistic tables at once. For example if table A has 40 statistics I must break this into 2 update statistics statements. This is because some of these tables are really large and the application I am working on has a timeout on database calls.

I have been trying to parallelize this process. Firstly I tried to create jobs of max 20 stat tables per chunk and using `parallel.foreach`. However I was noticing even though I had set `maxDegreeOfParallelism` to 5 often only 3 queries were being performed on my database at a time. I have read about how `parallel.foreach` does some stuff with resource sharing/partitioning among threads but I don't feel like there is a reason to use this if I am just making a single database call per task.

I then tried creating tasks and limiting the number of active tasks using semaphores. Using the same 5 task limit I was able to see 5 queries running concurrently on the database, but overall did not notice much performance benefit over using parallel.foreach.

Now the one thing i'm really wondering is how the speed of this process scales with the number of running `Update Statistics`. Some things I have noticed, but may be wrong about. Whenever I try to run two `Update statistics` concurrently on the same table

```
--assume these are running in different tasks
Update Statistics A (stattable1, stattable2,....stattable20);
Update Statistics A (stattable21, stattable22....);
```

one query seems to be blocked until the other finishes. I guess this makes sense since we are trying to scan the same table.

Then, when running `Update Statistics` on two different tables concurrently

```
--assume these are running in different tasks
Update Statistics A (stattable1, stattable2,....);
Update Statistics B (stattable1, stattable2....);
```

I do notice that each query takes longer than if I were just to run one update at a time, however this delay doesnt seem to be completely blocking (i.e if  `Update Statistics A` takes 2 min and `Update Statistics B` takes 2 min then for them to both finish it might take 3 min to finish rather than 4). This is what I am really unsure of, how this performance scales as you run more queries in parallel.

Basically I am just wondering whether it makes more sense to use tasks vs parallel.foreach, as well as the best way to structure these queries to improve performance.

Comment: Why don't you just increase the timeout?

Comment: Why is an application updating all the statistics in your database? There are better mousetraps. Anyway, there is no way to make stats updates faster, except to make your I/O faster (which I suspect is the slowdown you're observing). They take what they take, you can trade performance for accuracy (e.g. smaller sample sizes), but that's about it.

Comment: @FrankerZ it's an application wide timeout, also there are usually only 5-10 tables with more than 20 statistics anyways so I don't think this really affects performance that much.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the application has an optimize feature that many users schedule to run nightly. My main question about performance was really about how exactly concurrent queries work in sqlserver. Like I do notice it's faster to run 2 queries concurrently than one after another. But surely this slows down at some point and i'm just unsure of what the limiting factor would be. At some point I notice queries that might take 1 minute running on their own take up to 10 minutes when running in parallel with like 5 other queries. Mostly curious about specifics about what determines this performance

Comment: So could many users schedule the same tables to be optimized all at the same time? That seems... well... sub-optimal. Why don't you just "optimize" all the tables and don't force them to force it? You're going to have to dig deeper into the metrics behind these queries to get any meaningful answers. There are about 86,000 reasons a query can be slower. We can't guess.

Comment: @AaronBertrand there are checks to prevent cases like that. Yeah I was mainly hoping there might be a tried and true way of parallelizing that I just wasn't able to find on google. I guess i'll just have to try and play around and see what gives me the best performance

Comment: @AaronBertrand, did you perhaps mean to say "just 'optimize' all the tables overnight and don't __*allow*__ users to do it"? :)  Leave the button on the UI, of course - just attach it to a random progress bar... [evil grin]

Comment: @Brian Well I meant don't make them think that the only way they can make their queries faster is by pressing the button. They shouldn't need to think that their queries are slow because you can fix "the problem" in various without making them click a button.

Comment: That's fair, @AaronBertrand, and I __*was*__ making assumptions about the application and who his users are.